# Arithmetic progressions in Van der Waerden's theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, ds.dynamical-systems

Recall that a syndetic subset of the integers is any $S\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ with bounded gaps, i.e. there is some $k< \omega$ so that consecutive members of $S$ have distance at most $k$. One way to state Van der Waerden's theorem is that every syndetic set contains arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions (which I will call APs).

Call an AP of the form $\{a, a+d,...,a+(\ell-1)d\}$ a $d$-AP of length $\ell$. Now fix a syndetic $S\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. For each $\ell < \omega$, let $d_\ell$ denote the least $d$ so that $S$ contains a $d$-AP of length $\ell$. My question is about the function $\ell\to d_\ell$. Is there a syndetic $S\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ where $d_\ell\to \infty$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes, in fact the sequence $S\subset \mathbb{N}$ indexed by [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) works, see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87923/sequences-without-long-arithmetic-progressions). Note that this sequence is syndetic because it contains one of $\{2n, 2n+1\}$ for every $n$. You can extend to the negatives by reflecting and trivially only lose a factor of two on $\ell$.

Comment: Thanks! The link you gave suggests the following idea which is quite intuitive. If $x\in [0,1]$ is irrational, let $S = \{n\in \mathbb{Z}: xn-\lfloor xn \rfloor\in [0, 1/2]\}$. Then this clearly has the property I want. How fast can  one make the function $\ell\to d_\ell$ grow?

Comment: Not too much to add to that answer - essentially what it shows is such a set $S_x$ will have long arithmetic progressions of common difference $d$ iff $xd$ is very close to an integer, and the length will be inversely proportional to how close this is. In particular the example $x=\phi$ should be best possible up to constants with $\{xd\} \ge d^{-1}$ by standard Diophantine approximation results, and so $d_{\ell}$ growing linearly in $\ell$ is best possible using this construction.