A uniform version of Van der Waerden's theorem
The following ``uniform version" of Van der Waerden's theorem seems reasonable to me.

Question: Is it true that for any partition of $\mathbb{N}=A_0 \sqcup A_1$, there is some $d$ so that there is some $i\in \{0,1\}$ for which $A_i$ contains arbitrarily long arithmetic progression with fixed difference $d$?

It can be shown the question has a positive answer for ``almost every partition". However, it can be proved, by a dynamic system method shown by one of my colleague,  the question has a negative answer.
Now I wonder whether this is a known result? Or is there any further study along this line?

No, the colouring given by the Thue-Morse sequence gives a counterexample - see the question and answers to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87923/sequences-without-long-arithmetic-progressions

@ThomasBloom The first word of your comment should be "Yes" instead of "No".

Ah, tricky - I was answering 'No' to the bolded Question. But that would be a 'Yes' to the followup question, true.
